# New oven/microwave combination unit with 4 wire pigtail

Tags: microwave-oven

I have a new oven/micro unit just delivered. It has a 4 wire pigtail and the old unit had a 3 prong 30a plug to a 3 prong female wall plug. Can I use the same wall outlet and plug or do I need to change out the wall outlet to a four prong receptacle? Anyone?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. This question has already been answered [here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/14511); please check it out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I connect a dryer with a four prong plug to a three prong socket?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/14511/how-do-i-connect-a-dryer-with-a-four-prong-plug-to-a-three-prong-socket)

Comment: While the linked dup is a similar question, I’m not sure that changing the cord to 3-prong is the best answer for this question.

Comment: Can you turn the breaker for the oven off then post a photo of the inside of the outlet box for the oven receptacle?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible the newest units are simply not made for a 3-prong receptacle (and that would be reasonable since grounds are important to protect electronics from people).

In that case, and regardless for safety, you have the ability to **retrofit ground**.   This involves running a #10 bare wire via *any achievable route* back to any of several locations:

- the service panel the power comes out of
- any other appliance or junction which has a #10 ground wire or larger going back to that same panel
- the grounding electrode wire that grounds the service panel to your water pipe or ground rods